# multiple list compare with file line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Code (incomplete):

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list3 = ['12' '13' '14']
for list_in in list1:
    with open("buffer_file") as f:
        for line in f:
            if len(line.split(" ")) >= 3:
                var1 = line.split(" ")
                if var1[0] == list1[0] and var[1] == list2[0] and var[3] == list3[0]:
```

`buffer_file`:

```
no
priority enabled
1 a 12  
2 b 13
3 d 14
pump it
```

What I am trying here is if in file line and list values are matched then print file line is matched.

Example 1:

```
 list1[0], list2[0], list3[0]
```

is matched with line contains `1 a 12` values so print `matched`

Example 2:

```
 list1[1], list2[1], list3[1]
```

is matched with line contains `2 b 13` values so print `matched`

Example 3:

```
list1[2], list2[2], list3[2]
```

is  not matched because  line contains `3 d 12` values print not matched and also print not matched element that is `d`

Any one please suggest me what is the best way get this done. I am struck in middle of my code.

Comment: Its incomplete code and checking my approach is correct or is there any other easy way i can achieve this

Comment: What's the purpose of the second and third element of your lists, you don't seem to do anything with them?

Comment: we have to use them and verify with each elements with lines

Comment: Also please provide the buffer_file for which you have posted the desired output.

Comment: But your code only uses the first elements (index 0). Do you want to check whether the condition of the last line of your code is true for at least one index?

Comment: buffer_file is pasted as output file:

Comment: Ok, in that case we need the result you expect to be printed for that buffer_file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144056/discussion-between-asteroid4u-and-timgeb).

Comment: no thanks :) please update your question such that it contains a proper MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - I'll check back later.

Comment: Just edited my questions and provided more examples. Please let me know if not understand

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` your three lists so that you can grab and check their values as triplets of aligned elements.

```
expected = zip(list1, list2, list3)
print expected 
[ ('1', 'a', '12'), ('2', 'b', '13'), ... ]
```

If the lines in the file match your list elements one to one, you can then use `zip()` again to loop through the expected and actual values together. `zip()` is your friend. (If the file has extra lines, use a variable to walk down the list of triples.)

```
with open("buffer_file") as f:
    for exp, actual in zip(expected, f):
        if exp == actual.split():   # compares two 3-tuples
           <etc.>
```

Comment: Note that OP is using Python 2.7, where `zip` does not return an iterator.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines a bit here. Essentially sounds line you want to ignore all the lines are't triples, enumerate over the file and find matches in your original list.

```
values = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['12', '13', '14'],
]

def triples(line):
    return len(line.split()) >= 3


with open("test_file.txt") as f:
    content = filter(triples, (map(str.strip, f.readlines())))
    # Loop over the file keeping track of index
    for index, line in enumerate(content):
        # Compare split line and triples
        if line.split() == list(map(itemgetter(index), values)):
            print(line)
```

Gives me, where "test_file.txt" contains your listed input

```
1 a 12
2 b 13
```